# Vue 3 v-if not reacting to changes within a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, conditional-rendering

**What works:**

I want to render an element only if some boolean value is true using Vue 3. This is an example following the Vue 3 documentation and it works just fine:

Template:

```
...
<div id="btnReady" @click="ready = !ready">
   <img v-if="!ready" src="ready.svg" alt="" />
   <img v-else src="unready.svg" alt="" />
</div>
...
```

Script:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue";
    let ready = ref(false);
</script>
```

**What I do not understand:**

That makes perfect sense to me, except i don't really understand the need of `ref()`. I read the documentation about it and didn't really understand how/why vue requires the initialization like this `let ready = ref(false)`and why using `let ready = false` won't react to changes to the `ready` variable.

**What does NOT work:**

Beside toggling a boolean value, the `onclick` handler should also perform some other actions. So instead of toggling the value like this `onclick="ready = !ready"` i want to call a function `onclick="toggleReady"`. The value of `ready` will be toggled within the function and some other actions will be executed.
The function is executed on click just fine **but** Vue does NOT react to the changes of the `ready` variable and the `v-if` statement does not "work" properly -> the element is still visible.

Template:

```
<div id="btnReady" @click="toggleReady">
    <img v-if="!isReady" src="ready.svg" alt="" />
    <img v-else src="unready.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script setup>
   import { ref } from "vue";
   let ready = ref(false);
   let toggleReady = () => {
       ready = !ready;
       // do some more stuff
   };
</script>
```

Can someone explain me this behaviour and how I can fix it?

PS: I also tried using a `computed` property in the `v-if` statement instead of a normal variable. Didn't work...

Comment: `ready.value = !ready.value;` as per *[documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref)*

Comment: note: if you're using `vite` - you can try the experimental [Reactivity Transform](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#explicit-opt-in) by adding `{reactivityTransform: true}`  fir `vue` in *vite.config.js* ... i.e. `plugins: [ vue({reactivityTransform: true}) ]` - which would allow you to drop the `.value` - but it is experimental

Comment: This works indeed. But why can we simply write `onclick="ready = !ready"` but have to write `ready.value =  !ready.value` when using a function?
Also why do i have to access the `value` property in the script section but when checking in the `v-if` statement i check like this `v-if="ready"` and not `v-if="ready.value"`?

Comment: EDIT: I should have read the docs before asking questions... Makes sense to me, although i think the aproach in Vue 2 was more straight forward to understand. Not sure how exactly this was done there tho.

Comment: `how exactly this was done there` how what was done where? the first code doesn't need to use `.value` ... as documented

Answer (score 4):

As @Bravo mentioned in the comments you should use in your js code `ready.value = !ready.value;` instead of `ready = !ready;` (https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref)

If you just want to change the source of an image, you can use conditional attribute rendering like so:

```
  ...
    <div id="btnReady" @click="ready = !ready">
       <img :src="!ready ? 'ready.svg' : 'unready.svg'" alt="" />
    </div>
    ...
```